# how to call and use my pk given in urls in a class based view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have this code in urls

```
from .views import testview

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<pk>', testview.as_view(), name='test')
]
```

And this is my view :

```
class testview(FormView):
    template_name = 'test/test.html'
    form_class = ExampleForm


    def form_valid(self, form):
        cl = form.cleaned_data
        book= Book(user_id='pk',
                   book = cl['book'],
                   price = book.price )

        return create_book(self.request, book)
```

So how can I take that `pk` in the urls and use it inside the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`self.kwargs`** to access the URL parameters...

For example:

```
class testview(FormView):
    template_name = 'test/test.html'
    form_class = ExampleForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pk_from_url = self.kwargs['pk']
        # rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object during the `dispatch` for the view and the url param is added to the `kwargs` for the view;

```
class TestFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'test/test.html'
    form_class = ExampleForm
    book = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.book = get_object_or_404(
            Book, pk=kwargs.get('pk')
        )
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Reading these docs may be useful; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch